# Extra character in json_encode result

Tags: codeigniter, json

I am trying to create a properly formatted JSON result using CodeIgniter, but in the result shown below, it looks like there is an extra hyphen or dash character, as shown here:

[image: JSON with extra character]

Here is the code that I am using to generate the query result:

```
function y($mun){   
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT RollNum , Address, v2_lat, v2_lng
                       FROM mytable 
                       WHERE Municipality = '".$mun."' LIMIT 100"); 
echo json_encode($q->result());
exit;
}
```

Can someone explain why there appears to be an extra character appearing?  Thanks.

Comment: I bet if you click the hyphens it will collapse the block; i.e they're not actually part of the JSON.

Comment: these chars are showing by viewer not in JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using some of the Chrome or other browers extensions/addons like **JSONView** - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en

So here the '**-**' is just a button to minimize or collapse that particular block.

Its not in the `JSON`, but provided by the the `addon`.

If you `disable` the `extension/addon` for a moment and then try to print the `JSON`, you'll see no '**-**' there.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Parag.  Not only do I lose the '-' when I turn off the JSONView extension, but I also lose all that great formatting provided by it.  Now that I understand what it is, I'm comfortable for leaving the extension working.  Thanks for your help.